# Is it possible to solve this set of equations?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

Let's have system of equations:
$$
\tag 1 [\nabla \times \mathbf E ] = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} ,
$$
$$
\tag 2 [\nabla \times \mathbf B] = \sigma \mathbf E + A(\mu \mathbf K + C \mathbf B ),
$$
$$
\tag 3 \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} = D (\mathbf K \cdot \mathbf E) , \quad [\nabla \times \mathbf K] = k \mathbf K .
$$
Here $A, C, D, \sigma , k$ are constant numbers, $\mathbf K$ is known.

If we can neglect term $\mu \mathbf K$ in $(2)$ and when $[\nabla \times \mathbf B] = k_{0}\mathbf B , k_{0} << k$, the solution is known. But what to do with system $(1)-(3)$ in general case? Can it be solved analytically, is there some exact solution exist?

Comment: It seems there is an inconsistency. Taking Fourier transforms, so $
\mathbf{\nabla }\rightarrow i\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{K}\rightarrow \mathbf{
\tilde{K}}$, and
$
i\mathbf{k}\times \mathbf{\tilde{K}}=k\mathbf{\tilde{K}.}
$
But the left hand side is orthogonal to $\mathbf{\tilde{K}}$ so $\mathbf{
\tilde{K}}$ must vanish.

Comment: The fourier variable $p$ doesn't coincide with constant $k$ which I have given in an description. So after taking fourier transformation we can get
$$
-i[\mathbf p \times \tilde{\mathbf{ K}}] = k \tilde {\mathbf {K}}.
$$
It can be also observed that each function 
$$
\mathbf K = [\nabla \times [\nabla \times (\mathbf e \psi )]] + [\nabla \times \mathbf e \psi ], \quad \Delta \psi + k^{2} \psi = 0, \quad |\mathbf n|^{2} = 1
$$
satisfies equation. For example, $\mathbf B = A (cos (kz), sin(kz))$.

Comment: It is not $p$ being unequal to $k$ but $p×K^~$ being orthogonal to $K^~$.

Comment: @Urgje : you can still verify that solution $(sin(kz), cos(kz), 0)$ satisfies equation $[\nabla \times \mathbf B] = k\mathbf B$.

Comment: You convinced me. Although $\mathbf{\tilde{K}}(\mathbf{p})\mathbf{\cdot \{p}\times \mathbf{\tilde{K}}(
\mathbf{p})\}=0$ this does not hold for $\mathbf{K(x)\cdot }\{\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{K(x)\}}$ as your example shows.

Comment: I still have a problem with your equation $\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{K}=k\mathbf{K}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{K}$ is a vector, then $\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{K}$ is a pseudovector or vice-versa. Thus, unless $k$ is a pseudoscalar, there is an inconsistency. Can you explain where the equations come from? Maxwell's equations for a conducting medium?

Comment: @Urgje : yes, $k$ seems to be scalar. The system I'm trying to solve is magnetohydrodynamics which is modified by field $\mu$ (refers to pseudoscalar). Constant $C$ in my equation is also pseudoscalar. Here is corresponding question on physics.SE (there is different description there):
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143340/how-to-solve-the-following-set-of-equations-magnetohydrodynamics-with-anomaly-t .

Comment: Pardon, pseudoscalar.